# Does the mean of an iid random sample lie between minima/maxima almost surely or with large probability for large enough sample size?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let  $n \in \mathbb{N},$ and $\{ X_1 \dots X_n\}$ be iid random variables, each following the distribution of $X.$ For each $n$, consider the minima and maxima of $X_i$'s, i.e. $m_n:= min_{1 \le i \le n}X_i, M_n:=max_{1 \le i \le n}X_i.$ Note that $m_n, M_n$ are random variables for each fixed $n.$

My question is: can we say, if $\mathbb{E}[X]$ exists, then there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}, $ so that $ \forall n \ge N:$

$$ m_n \le \mathbb{E}[X] \le M_n  \hspace{2mm}a.s. ?$$

This is rather intuitive, but a proof of it, if true, would be nice to have. If it's not true, then can we say that it's true for a large enough subset, i.e. $\forall \epsilon > 0, $ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}, $ so that $ \forall n \ge N:$

$$P[ m_n \le \mathbb{E}[X] \le M_n] > 1 - \epsilon ?$$

$$$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is NO for the first question and YES for the second.

Let $(X_i)$ be i.i.d. $N(0,1)$. Then $P(M_n <EX)=P(M_n <0)>0$ for each $n$ since $X_i<0$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ with probability $\frac  1{2^{n}}$.

Note that $P(X_1 <EX) <1$. Hence $P(M_n <EX)= [P(X_1 <EX)]^{n} \to 0$. This gives $P(EX \leq M_n) \to 1$. Similarly $P(m_n\leq EX) \to 1$. Hence  the assertion in your second part is true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think there're few typos (e.g. $XE$ and $x_i > -0$) on the first line, could you please fix them?

Comment: @LearningMath I hope I have corrected al the errors now.

Comment: Yes, thank you!